# Expanding an argument within single quotes

Tags: bash, arguments, json

I'm trying to create a function that executes the following

composer config repositories.foo '{"type": "path", "url": "/b/foo-bundle"}'

I'm starting with

```bash
lb() { composer config repositories.$1 '{"type": "path", "url": "/b/$1-bundle" }' ; }
lb foo
```

But because the argument (a json string) is inside single quotes, it's generate $1-bundle instead of foo-bundle.

I'm sure there's a way to escape this, but I can't seem to hack my way through it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than literally embed that contents the `$1` into the json string which you could do with:

```
lb() {
  composer config "repositories.$1" '
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "/b/'"$1"'-bundle"
    }'
}
```

You could also get `jq` to generate the json using the proper encoding with:

```
lb() {
  composer config "repositories.$1" "$(
    URL="/b/$1-bundle" jq -cn '
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url": $ENV.URL
      }')"
}
```

That way, it works correctly even if `$1` contains characters that are special in the JSON syntax (not that it should happen for URLs).

Beware that `jq` transforms bytes that can't be part of UTF-8 characters to `�` (U+FFFD the *replacement character*). JSON strings can't hold arbitrary sequence of bytes, only UTF-8 encoded characters.

In a URL anyway, those bytes should be encoded as `%XX`. `jq` does have a `@uri` operator to URI-encode a string so you could do:

```
lb() {
  composer config "repositories.$1" "$(
    URL="/b/$1-bundle" jq -cn '
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url": ($ENV.URL | @uri)
      }')"
}
```

However, unfortunately, that would apply *after* the translation to `�`, so wouldn't let you properly URI-encode any byte sequence (like the ones that can't be decoded as UTF-8).

You'd need the URI encoding to be done before `jq`. If using `ksh93` instead of `bash`, that could be done with its builtin `printf` for instance:

```
function lb {
  typeset -x URL=${
    LC_ALL=C printf '%(url)q' "/b/$1-bundle"
  }
  composer config "repositories.$1" "${
    jq -cn '
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url": $ENV.URL
      }'
  }"
}
```

Or you could use proper programming languages like `perl` or `ruby` that come with proper URI / JSON manipulation modules.

Beware `ksh93`'s `printf`, like `jq`'s `@uri` encode `/` as `%2F` which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Thanks!  I particularly like the explanation of how to incorporate jq.  Plus, your code looks so much cleaner!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do to make the shell expand `$1` inside single-quotes, single-quoting is that strong. You need `$1` to be outside of single-quotes. You can close the single-quoting, double-quote `$1` and open single-quoting again:

```
… '{"type": "path", "url": "/b/'"$1"'-bundle" }'
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^  single-quoted, will be passed as-is
#                                ^^              double-quoted, will be expanded
# ^                            ^^  ^^          ^ quote removal will remove these
```

[You should also double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) `$1` that appears elsewhere (`repositories.$1`).